# is using non English words for paths recommended?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm working on a Drupal site which has a non-english language.I want to change the paths to something better than node/[nid].Nodes also have a non-english title and I want to set the path to content/[node-title].does it cause any problem?does it affect on SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [transliteration module](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) in combination with [pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to transliterate any characters in my node title beyond ASCII 128 and automatically create friendly urls for each of my nodes.

This combination works really well! :)

Whether it is actually necessary or advantageous to remove unicode characters from your site's URLs is a subject on which I'm sure there would be many different opinions.

The [Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) doesn't transliterate, but if you need to send your site's url's in an email, then things can quickly get out of hand and look ugly: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

I have no experience if unicode characters in URLs affect SEO.